# Is there a way to use GSAP's scrollToPlugin to scroll to a div ID?

Tags: jquery, gsap

In the [documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/ScrollToPlugin/), it lists a variety of ways to use the plugin but they all seem to require a number to input (e.g. "scrollTo:{y:250}"). I'm wondering if, instead of a number, there is a way to input a div id.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.full-streams-link').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        TweenLite.to(window, .4, {
            scrollTo: {y:500},
            ease: Power2.easeOut,
            force3D: true
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the y value, you can pass in the position top:

You could do

```
y: $('#element').position().top
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there anyway to make it -10px from the `#element`? Edit: nevermind. I can just add `-10` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since the GSAP version 1.19.0 you can do it simply by:

`TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:"#someID"});`

you can find more info at: [ScrollToPlugin Documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/Plugins/ScrollToPlugin)